# Why I get "Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive" with TAR command?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, tar

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.aboutdebian.com/tar-backup.htm) to full backup my linux / Ubuntu 12.04 after a fresh restore.

my code in `fullserver.sh`:

```
tar -cvpf /backups/fullbackup.tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc
--exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups .
```

gives after executing `./backups/fullserver.sh` the following error:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information. 
./backups/fullserver.sh: line 2: --exclude=sys: command not found
```

Any help to resolve this issue? I read somewhere that I have to remove "/" from the tar line, but I'm not sure that this is true...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command should be just one line:

```
tar -cvpf /backups/fullbackup.tar --directory=/ --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=backups .
```

It seems you've split it into two lines.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I did that and get the following ( astra3177:~# ./backups/fullserver.sh
tar: /backups/fullbackup.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now )

Comment: Most likely the folder `/backup/` doesn't exist. Use another one or create it using `sudo mkdir /backup/`

Comment: The folder is ( backups) and the file .sh is inside it. maybe a problem with folder's permission ( chmod ) ?

Comment: I found it YEEEEESSSS, in fact, I should remove "/" from ( /backups/fullbackup.tar), so now it is like that ( backups/fullbackup.tar, and it is work :)

Answer (score 23):

I encountered this warning when trying to execute the command without specifying the zipped file name. For example:

`tar -zcvf directoryName`

The warning was not issued when I executed this:

`tar -zcvf directoryName.tar.gz directoryName/`

Answer (score 0):

I recently got that error too. Turns out I forgot to specify the files to add to the archive:

```bsh
tar -cf hello.tar
```

After I selected the current directory as the files to add, it worked:

```bsh
tar -cf hello.tar ./*
```